# Google Container Builder: How to cache dependencies between two builds

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-builder

We are migrating our container building process to Google Container Builder. We have multiple repo using Node or Scala.

As of actual container builder features, is it possible to cache dependencies between two builds (ex: node_modules, .ivy, ...). It's really time (money) consuming to download everything each time.

I know it's possible to build a custom docker image with all packaged within, but we would prefer avoiding this solution.

For example can we mount a persistent volume for that purpose, as we used to do with DroneIO? or even better automatically like in Bitbucket Pipelines?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GCB doesn't currently support mounting a persistent volume across builds.

In the meantime, the team recently published a document outlining some options for speeding up builds, which might be useful: https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/speeding-up-builds

In particular, caching generated output to Google Cloud Storage and pulling it in at the beginning of your build might help in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Guys is this still valid today?